# How do I access my app's package folder in Android using Adobe AIR / Flex?

Tags: android, apache-flex, directory

I have an application for Android built using Flex. I need to save some configurations and data so I want to know how I can access the package-specific folder for my app instead of creating my own folder and writing there.

The package-specific folder I'm talking about is at **/sdcard/Android/data/com.mysite.myapp/**. Do I just access it directly via that path or is there a variable for File class that I'm not aware of?

The reason why I want to save onto this folder is because, if I create my own folder and save there, that would require my app to request the permission to access SD card contents. Something I don't want to include in my permission list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For app specific files, you can choose either `applicationDirectory` (read only), or `applicationStorageDirectory`.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/File.html

Comment: So there's no way of referencing to the `/sdcard/Android/data/com.mysite.myapp/` path of my app? Because that place is where most of the applications I have store their data and I figured it would be wise to follow that trend.

Comment: `applicationDirecty` is probably that very path. And even if it isn't, it would be wise to use what Adobe has documented / is recommending.